# I need help using pre_get_comments to limit comments in the comments admin screen

Tags: wp-query, comments, admin, actions

I am trying to limit the comments in the comments admin screen to:

1. Display all comments for the current user
2. Display all the comments made on the current user's post

```
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
    
    add_action('pre_get_comments', function($wp_query) {

        global $user_ID;

        // all current user comments
        $wp_query->set( 'user_id', $user_ID );

        // FIXME: condition to get comments made on current user's post
        
    });
}
```

I am facing two problems:

1. The code generates comments for all users and seems to ignore `$wp_query->set( 'user_id', $user_ID )`
2. I can't figure out a condition for the FIXME statement

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you

## Update

Unfortunately, 'post__in', 'user_is', and similar arguements limit the query instead expanding it.

As a result, I used a very long appraoch to get what the results that I want. However, I am waiting for an improved version of my appraoch before I can accept an answer.

Here's what I revised:

```
add_action('pre_get_comments', function($wp_comment_query) {

    global $wpdb;
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    
    $post_ids = "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_author = $user_ID 
    ";
    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_results($post_ids, ARRAY_N);
    $post_ids = array_column($post_ids, '0');
    $post_ids = implode(',', $post_ids);

    $comment_ids = "
        SELECT $wpdb->comments.comment_ID 
        FROM $wpdb->comments
        WHERE $wpdb->comments.user_id = $user_ID
        OR $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID IN ($post_ids)
    ";
    
    $comment_ids = $wpdb->get_results($comment_ids, ARRAY_N);
    $comment_ids = array_column($comment_ids, '0');
    
    $wp_comment_query->query_vars['comment__in'] = $comment_ids;

});
```

Comment: The update that I provided takes input from @Sally and it works, but I think that it can be refactored and that is why I will not post my update as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

In response to the new code in the updated question, you could actually use [`$wpdb->get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) with a single SQL command via a JOIN clause, like so:

```php
$query = "SELECT c.comment_ID FROM $wpdb->comments c
    JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID
WHERE c.user_id = $user_ID
    OR p.post_author = $user_ID";

$comment_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query );
```

However, instead of running that manually via the `pre_get_comments` hook, you could actually use the [`comments_clauses` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_clauses/) to add the above JOIN clause and WHERE conditions to the SQL command generated by `WP_Comment_Query`.

```php
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', function ( $pieces ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

    if ( false === strpos( $pieces['join'], "JOIN $wpdb->posts ON" ) ) {
        $pieces['join'] .= " JOIN $wpdb->posts ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = comment_post_ID";
    }

    $pieces['where'] .= " AND (user_id = $user_ID OR {$wpdb->posts}.post_author = $user_ID)";

    return $pieces;
} );
```

So try that, which should return:

1. Comments made by the current user on *any posts*, and
2. Comments by *other users*, but only on the posts where the current user is the author.

### Original Answer

The first (and only) parameter from the [`pre_get_comments` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_comments/) is actually an instance of the [`WP_Comment_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/) and not `WP_Query`, so the `$wp_query->set()` won't work because `WP_Comment_Query` does not have the `set()` method.

But you can directly access the `$query_vars` property in `WP_Comment_Query` to change the value of query args like the `user_id`. So for example with that arg, you would use `$wp_query->query_vars['user_id'] = $user_ID;`.

As for the `FIXME` part, try with the [`post_author` arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/#parameters): `$wp_query->query_vars['post_author'] = $user_ID;` which should work if you're indeed trying to display only the comments made by the current user on the posts where that user is the author.

PS: I would rename `$wp_query` to `$query` or maybe `$wp_comment_query`.. I would also use `$user_ID = get_current_user_id();` instead of relying upon the `$user_ID` *global*.

Comment: `$wp_query->query_vars['post_author'] = $user_ID` restricts the comments to only posts made by the current user. If only there was a way to add this argument as an "OR" statement in the query instead of and "AND"

Comment: I think that i should find a way to use `post__in` instead of `post_author`

Comment: According to WordPress: post__in  = Array of post IDs to include affiliated comments for. It is actually returning zero comments and when pass an array of current user posts ids to post__in? What gives

Comment: Actually, with the original code in the question, have you already tried replacing the `$wp_query->set( 'user_id', $user_ID )` with `$wp_query->query_vars['user_id'] = $user_ID; $wp_query->query_vars['post_author'] = $user_ID;` ? What was the code you tried with? And if I'm not mistaken, the new code in your updated question is basically leading to the same outcome.. 

Comment: Yes, and it restricted all comments to $user_ID

Comment: So I was mistaken (I didn't really check your new code). But anyway, try the new code in my answer (remove the code you currently have now..) and let me know.

Comment: Also, you should ensure the filter/code is applied only when necessary, to avoid messing with other comments queries. E.g. Do a `if ( is_admin() )` check..

Comment: I do have that check